# How to make WPF animations without expression blend

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, expression-blend

Is there a way or a tool i can use to make WPF animations and controls without using Expression Blend...maybe just using Visual Studio 2008 or something???

Comment: You should go through and accept answers (click the check mark) to your past questions. More people would be willing to help you if they got the rep they deserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio.

ALSO:

Visual Web Developer

[XAMLPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx)

If you're looking for a visual XAML tool and can't swing Blend, take a look at:

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) 
Even though the page says for Silverlight two, the designer says:

> The latest beta of Kaxaml works with
>   Silverlight 3 with you doing anything.
>   That said, I’m looking to expand the
>   support and finally bump SL support
>   out of beta. Unfortunately, Kaxaml
>   takes a back seat to paying gigs these
>   days so the best way to get a new
>   release of Kaxaml is to not hire me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create animations entirely in XAML. In fact, I prefer to do so. I find the Expression Blend interface confusing (or maybe I am just too lazy to learn it). I like to use [kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) to experiment. It comes with a bunch of XAML snippets, including an animation one to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in visual studio, but the designer isn't much use so you will be in XML mode a lot, and animations generally take a *lot* of xaml!  If you really want to do it then take a look at the documentation for DoubleAnimation (for animating properties) and Storyboard (for grouping animations)

Comment: Ok, I haven't tried using overly complex animations so far but for simple fading and moving around writing them directly in XAML works pretty well. But yes, they take an awful lot of markup in some cases.

Comment: Yeah, it's doable, and fine for simple things, but animations are one of the few things I usually turn to Blend for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read Jeff Paries's book "[Foundation Silverlight 2 Animation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430215690)" - it sounds like you are going to need it.

Seriously, I could not imagine writing serious animations without Blend.

Comment: I can't imagine actually using Blend. Seriously this tool is so behind Visual Studio, I can't even use the keyboard to navigate between most parts of the app and the XAML editor lacks the keyboard shortcuts and all of that from Visual Studio making it difficult for developers to use.

Comment: I would say that if you are using Blend to manually edit XAML, you're missing out on what Blend is all about. I agree: if you want to write XAML, I would use Visual Studio.  What I am saying is I couldn't conceive of wanting to manually write XAML for something as complex as an animation, especially when I have such a simple way of doing it using Blend.

I think the real problem lies in assuming parity between the two tools: Visual Studio is an IDE, Blend is a vector-oriented GUI designer.  They serve two distinct purposes and should be employed accordingly.