# Tools for animations in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm looking for a tool to create animations in WPF. The only tool that I know is Blend. Blend is for my purposes to heavy and I don't have a license. Therefore I'm looking for a free tool - like XAMLPad - to create animations. Does anyone know some tools?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507971/how-to-make-wpf-animations-without-expression-blend

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there aren't any. By the way Blend for windows phone 7 is free.